# What does Console.ReadLine(); do in the code below?

Tags: c#

If I comment Console.ReadLine(), only 0 is printed. But when I uncomment it, all 99 numbers are printed. What does readline do? Having hard time to grasp this.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication40
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Method();
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Main");
        //Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Method()
    {
        Task.Run(new Action(LongTask));
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Method");
    }

    private static void LongTask()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(i + ",");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The application terminate before the task is completed. When you add the `Console.ReadLine()` the application will wait until there is something in the Input stream, therefore enough time for the Task to finish execution

Comment: You are not waiting for the task to finish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Console.ReadLine()` causes the main thread to block until the user types something, which allows the other thread to finish its task.  Without it, the main thread and hence the program terminate before the task has a chance to finish

Comment: No it is nothing like that.  I would suggest you read the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

`Console.ReadLine()` is trying to get input (from the user, probably). So it is stopping the program while it waits. While this is going on, `LongTask()` is running, printing 0 through 99.

If you comment out `Console.ReadLine()`, the `Main()` function exits, and the program ends, before `LongTask()` has time to print all the numbers.

Comment: That's what Task.Run( ) does, yes.